# Package doesn't work if run from cmd or from the .py file.... PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium, module, package

I noticed a problem with python (windows). If I create a program (even simple) and I import a package, it works if I run it from the python shell
but if I run it from the `.py` file or with the `cmd (C:\Python34\program.py)` it doesn't.

Make it clear:

**Program 1**

```
from selenium import webdriver
print("have a good day")
```

**Program2**

```
import pyautogui
print("be happy")
pyautogui.moveT(300,300)
```

**Error program 1**

```
Traceback (most recent calls)
 File"C:\Python34\program.py" line 1, in <module>
  from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

**Error Program 2**

```
Traceback (most recent calls)
 File"C:\Python34\program.py" line 1, in <module>
  import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

So I don't understand why it doesn't find/recognize the module if I doesn't run it from the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ModuleNotFoundError` states that the module 'selenium' and 'pyautogui' isn't available for the python interpreter (the one you invoked to execute your script with). Since you have tried executing the same code from within the shell interpreter, the problem might be because of having multiple python installations on your Windows system.

When you have multiple versions of python installed on your system, then there is **a possibility that the package(s) you tried installing using `pip` command doesn't end up residing inside the python version** you were expecting them to be in.

Before you do anything, **check which python version the `pip` utility is referring to:**

`$ pip --version
pip <ver> from path/to/pip (python <version>)`

If the python version at the end of the above result is 2.x, then it means that the selenium package you tried installing using `pip install selenium` ended up inside python 2 environment.

However, when you try to execute the python script, the 3.x interpreter is being invoked. In which case, the module will not be available. Here's what you can do:

**Install package using pip3 command:**

`pip3 install selenium`

This will install the *selenium* or any other package, inside python 3 installation only. Now you should be able to execute the script without any errors. Same goes for *pyautogui*.

Also, note that **under Microsoft Windows, the `python` command usually invokes the Python 2 shell interpreter**. In which case, you were easily able to run your code (which required selenium) without any errors. There is another utility called `py`, under Windows. You can learn more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896496/what-is-the-difference-between-py-and-python-in-the-terminal)

**EDIT:** *selenium* is not a pre-installed package

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciated