# py is not recognized as an internal or external operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-2.7

These are my environment variables:

> PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\GitExtensions;C:\Program Files\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files
> (x86)\GitExtensions;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\oprisvlad2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\oprisvlad2\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
> Menu\Programs\Python 2.7;

The C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts are added but "py" is still unrecognized.
I restarted my machine several times. I have look all over for solutions but none of them worked for me. I prefer something that works from the command prompt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error "'py.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384312/how-to-fix-error-py-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The py.exe executable is not found in the paths specified to windows environment. py.exe is a launcher for detecting specific python installations.

Try `python` to launch the default python.

Make sure that the paths to the python executable file are placed before the the windows app dir, otherwise it could lead to windows triggering to-be-installed python.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 2.7;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\oprisvlad2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

If you have py.exe somewhere, add the absolute path to evironment variable. Usually for newer python versions, if you install python via windows installer, the py is automatically added to the env variables.

Comment: Well, 'python' will prompt me to the microsoft store to install it. I have already installed it.

Comment: Could you check which python executable (pythonxx.exe) is listed in C:\Python27? And are you sure you want to work with python2.7? - If not, try searching for python 3.9 in windows app store or directly download the windows installer to go for the a recent stable release.

Comment: In that directory I have python.exe and pythonw.exe. Yes, python 2.7 is required for my project.

Comment: What terminal do you use? windows cmd oder some other terminal?
If windows could you type - echo %PATH% and if other unix based ones echo $PATH to check it the path is read in correctly. Also try putting 'C:\Python27' as the first parameter.

Comment: yes, windows cmd

Comment: Can you run it by specifying the abs path to the exe `C:\Python27\python.exe` ?

Comment: Yes, it can be run with that abs path.

Comment: Then please put `C:\Python27` and `C:\Python27\Scripts` somewhere in near the starting section of the environment var paths. What does `where python` output?

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Users\oprisvlad2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Comment: Remove  `C:\Users\oprisvlad2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` or move 
`C:\Python27` and other python27 paths so that it comes before `C:\Users\oprisvlad2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

Comment: @OprVld Just to test you can append to the PATH from cmd using `set PATH=C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;%PATH%` .

Comment: My path now looks like this but py is still not recognized: PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Python27\;C:\Users\oprisvlad2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\oprisvlad2\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 2.7

Comment: Did you alread try `python` instead of `py` after your changes?