# Unable to run Python 3.7 on Windows 10 "Permission denied"

Tags: python, windows, bash, git

When trying to run Python 3.7 on Windows 10 with Git Bash I get the following error:

```
$ python --version
bash: /c/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied
```

What to do?

Edit: I solved (or rather circumvented) this by installing python using scoop and using cmder instead of Git Bash.

Comment: Why is this question closed? *"We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow"* this question is about a very specific issue on using Python on Windows, it's 100% relevant to StackOverflow.

Comment: Yep. It helped me.

Answer (score 9):

Python isn't actually installed. That's a shim which should open the Windows store, but it only works from PowerShell or CMD (and only does that correctly some of the time). I recommend visiting the Python website and downloading and installing from there.

Here is the blog post announcing this "feature": https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/

This SuperUser article discussed solutions:
https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor

Comment: I've already installed though, and from the Python website. I can use it with PyCharm.

Comment: Make sure you add it to your `$PATH` from within Git Bash.

Comment: I did that as well.
`$ export path="$PATH:/c:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37" `

Comment: When installed "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe" is a special kind of appexec reparse point that's used by `CreateProcessW` to set up the security context that allows executing the real executable that's in a subdirectory of "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps". By design, this reparse point is not handled by the I/O manager or any filter drivers in the kernel, so code that naively tries to open that path with reparsing enabled (by default) will fail. bash, or more specifically Cygwin/MSYS2, does exactly this and thus needs to be patched in order to support appexec links.

Comment: You need to do `export PATH="/c/Users/Name/.../Python/Python37:$PATH`. Notice that the `$PATH` is after the new addition. That's because Linux will look in order at each of the directories in the `$PATH` and if the desired executable exists in the directory, it will use that one. Also, note that you do not want a `:` after `c` in the Linux `$PATH` since `:` is the separator character for path elements.

Comment: You mean bash, not Linux. git-bash is based on MSYS2, which is derived from Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I also received "Permission Denied" message from Git Bash. What worked for me was using "py":

```
py file_name.py
```

Reference: [Difference between Py and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896496/what-is-the-difference-between-py-and-python-in-the-terminal)