# How to get permissions to run Python code in Windows 10

Tags: python

I was trying to run this `decrypt.py` code on windows 10 in terminal, I have installed Python 3 in my Windows in Drive C, and this code is in Drive D. The terminal is run in Visual Studio Code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os
import os.path
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import time


class Encryptor:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def pad(self, s):
        return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

    def encrypt(self, message, key, key_size=256):
        message = self.pad(message)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)

    def encrypt_file(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
            plaintext = fo.read()
        enc = self.encrypt(plaintext, self.key)
        with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
            fo.write(enc)
        os.remove(file_name)

    def decrypt(self, ciphertext, key):
        iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
        return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")

    def decrypt_file(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
            ciphertext = fo.read()
        dec = self.decrypt(ciphertext, self.key)
        with open(file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:
            fo.write(dec)
        os.remove(file_name)

    def getAllFiles(self):
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        dirs = []
        for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(dir_path):
            for fname in fileList:
                if (fname != 'script.py' and fname != 'mykeys.txt.enc'):
                    dirs.append(dirName + "\\" + fname)
        return dirs

    def encrypt_all_files(self):
        dirs = self.getAllFiles()
        for file_name in dirs:
            self.encrypt_file(file_name)

    def decrypt_all_files(self):
        dirs = self.getAllFiles()
        for file_name in dirs:
            self.decrypt_file(file_name)


key = b'[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e'
enc = Encryptor(key)
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

if os.path.isfile('mykeys.txt.enc'):

    while True: 
        mykeys = str(input("Enter keys: "))
        enc.decrypt_file("mykeys.txt.enc")
        p = ''
        with open("mykeys.txt", "r") as f:
            p = f.readlines()
        if p[0] == mykeys:
            enc.encrypt_file("mykeys.txt")
            break

    while True:
        clear()
        choice = int(input(
            "1. Press '1' to encrypt file.\n2. Press '2' to decrypt file.\n3. Press '3' to Encrypt all files in the directory.\n4. Press '4' to decrypt all files in the directory.\n5. Press '0' to exit.\n"))
        clear()
        if choice == 1:
            enc.encrypt_file(str(input("Enter name of file to encrypt: ")))
        elif choice == 2:
            enc.decrypt_file(str(input("Enter name of file to decrypt: ")))
        elif choice == 3:
            enc.encrypt_all_files()
        elif choice == 4:
            enc.decrypt_all_files()
        elif choice == 0:
            exit()
        else:
            print("Please select a valid option!")

else: print("You don't have permission to read file.")
```

However, when I run it, Terminal gave me this response

```
PS D:\project\temp-and-humidity> & C:/Users/bleac/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe d:/project/temp-and-humidity/decrypt.py
You don't have permission to read file.
PS D:\project\temp-and-humidity>
```

What do I need to do to gain permissions to run this file on Windows 10? I was searching the way to run it similar to sudo but I am confused at how to use the `runas` command. Also, when I right click the file, it have no "Run as administrator" option.

[image]

edit: I will post the file in here, the file is in this zip in Google Drive.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sOYeu_XLGuYhV-FRPHtLKNTPDtPyCybY

Comment: open with, then python or choose an app then python

Comment: hmm I wondered why OP's Python installed on `AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps`? :/

Comment: I was installing Python 3 by Windows store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are installed Python 3 from Windows Store, that's why you got limited permission when trying to run scripts. Try to uninstall it, and install the Python from the [official webiste](https://www.python.org/downloads/) instead

https://www.python.org/downloads/

---

Btw, here is the related question you might interested [#59148628](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59148628/6241697)

Comment: Result: It works! But then the code tell me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'` so I run `pip install pycryptodome` and run the code again with both `python decrypt.py` and  `C:/Users/bleac/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe d:/project/temp-and-humidity/decrypt.py` but this times it tells me again that I do not have permissions. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: wait, how about `pycrypto` instead of `pycryptodome`?

Comment: I try `pycrypto` but it gave me the result as if I don't have it. The code must be specifically referencing `pycryptodome` in it. Still, I wonder what could be th source of the permissions problem since the Python path already got configured to `.../Local/Programs/...`

Comment: you might want to follow [this guide](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/installation.html#windows-from-sources-python-3-5-and-newer)

Comment: I followed the guide. It seems that my problem with pycryptodome has ended. Problem is, I keep getting a result of `You don't have permission to read file.` llike before I fix it again. I searched the way to fix it by disabling Windows Store Python(even after I uninstall it). And there is no more old location of Python reference in my Windows Environment Variables, only new one. Now I am very confused at it.

Comment: Update: I finally fixed it. It was about file requirement in the coding. It was my fault thinking it was other problems. Sorry for extending it. Now my problem got solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal on the path. and write this code
    python decrypt.py press ENTER