# python cmd still not recognized in VS shell

Tags: python, visual-studio

I dont wanna use 'py myfile.py', i use 'python myfile.py'.

- Running 'py file.py' works though.
- I do have python extension installed

> ```
> python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a 
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was 
> included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>     At line:1 char:1
> ```

VS studio still gives me error, but before that  i did "select python interpreter".
it's set at my std installation:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
```

I followed another similar question on SO, did restart - what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you're interested in is the difference between py and python.

If so the question is a possible duplicate of this [What is the difference between 'py' and 'python' in the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896496/what-is-the-difference-between-py-and-python-in-the-terminal)