# Why can't i use py command in Python 3.9.6?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I had python `3.9.4` and everything was fine then ! When i updated to `3.9.6` , i am not able to use `py` command .But i can use `python` command . Any fix for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896496/what-is-the-difference-between-py-and-python-in-the-terminal

Comment: Thank You for the reply @PaoloTormon . I have python launcher too  . I have been using python for a year and i have not come across something like this till now . 
Should i reinstall the launcher?

Comment: @KetZoomer have it already ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `alias py=python`. If you want the alias to persist, you should add it to your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` files.

Comment: if you don't mind could you please say the steps ..