# How to install git-filter-repo on Windows

Tags: git, github, version-control, windows-10, git-filter-repo

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/5049813), which recommends using [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo).

What I've tried; what happened:

- Download [just the file `git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/git-filter-repo), edit my PATH to include it, run `git-filter-repo`, `python git-filter-repo`, `python3 git-filter-repo`, `python git filter-repo`, `git filter-repo`. In all of these cases, the command (python, python3, git) cannot find the file/operation (git-filter-repo, filter-repo). (I'm always running these commands from my personal git folder that I want to use the git-filter-repo script on.)
- Clone [the repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), add the repo to my PATH. Run `git-filter-repo`, `python git-filter-repo`, `python3 git-filter-repo`. In all cases, the command cannot find the file/operation.
- I noticed that when I cloned, I ran into [the symlink issue mentioned in the install documentation](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/4bc9022afce5e2e138596bbecf4df310212ae164/INSTALL.md?plain=1#L176). So I copy/pasted `git-filter-repo` into `git-filter-repo.py`. Added the repo/folder `git-filter-repo` to my path. Again, tried the different commands, nothing worked.
- Same repo with `git-filter-repo.py` being edited, but now `git-filter-repo/git-filter-repo` is on the path. No luck.
- Same repo with `git-filter-repo.py` being edited, but now `git-filter-repo/git-filter-repo.py` is on the path. No luck.

**Is there something that I did that should have worked?** (I may have missed some combination of commands and path editing when testing.) **If not, how do I run git-filter-repo on my personal repo?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69356543/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-filter-repo+windows "*4. Run the command `git --exec-path` to see your Git exe directory.

5. From the `git-filter-repo` repo's root directory, copy the file `git-filter-repo` (about 160KB) into your Git exe directory.

6. In your command line where you use Git, type the command `git filter-repo`.*"

Comment: This solved it - feel free to post as answer or mark question as duplicate. Thank you.