# CMD has two versions of python

Tags: python

So I just installed the latest version of python, and I also changed the old 3.5 python version to 3.10 in my environment variables. There is no python 3.5 in the PATH inside environment variables, but when I run `py --version` in my CMD then it says `version 3.5`, but when I type `python --version` then it says `version 3.10.2`, is there a way to manually choose which version should be called on `py or python`?

[image: version prints]

Comment: Assuming you're on Windows, what does `where python` give you? What about `where py`? Alternatively for linux, `which python` and `which py`.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50896496/4177009) looks relevant.

Comment: @TheMungax [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/263980/switching-between-versions-of-python-installed-fro.html) seems to be exactly what you're looking for. Specifically `py -3.10`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a python virtual environment to control it. (venv)

Just one thing, you can create a venv only with the version or python which is installed.

Also you can use conda to manage different version of python.

Here is a tutorial to create a venv or use conda on windows :

https://medium.com/co-learning-lounge/create-virtual-environment-python-windows-2021-d947c3a3ca78#a904

Comment: So I just have to do the following in the python310 folder where I in CMD do: (1) `python -m venv virtual_env`, then (2) `.\virtual_env\Scripts\activate`, then the python version is set to be `3.10.2` when I run `py --version` or `python --version`?

Answer (score 0):

@The Mungax I am not sure but I can show you something that might help you
what is the Difference between “python” vs “py”

PYTHON

> The command python refers to the Python executable of the default
> Python installation. Technically, the path of this version is stored
> inside the PATH environment variable where your OS will search for the
> executable when processing any command.

PY

> The command py refers to the Python launcher, a utility that’s
> automatically installed into C:\Windows\ for any Python installation
> on Windows. All files in the Windows folder are accessible without
> needing to modify the PATH environment variable. Thus, the Python
> launcher automatically delegates the work to the latest Python version
> installed in your environment. However, you can also specify the used
> installation by means of a flag argument such as in py -3.6 to specify
> Python version 3.6.