# Git: py command not found

Tags: python, windows, git

I have been trying to initialize a git repository, but I can't even make the initial commit since it fails by giving me the error below. I tried uninstalling python and installing it again, running git bash as admin, but to no avail. Also... I couldn't find anything else with this error:

```
$ git commit -m "init"
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 11: py: command not found
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 12: py: command not found
```

Comment: What did you do before `git commit` to create the repository?

Comment: git init, git add . ,

Comment: there seems to be a `pre-commit` hook in `.git/hooks/`. If you never wanted it, you can simply remove it

Comment: If this was the result of a simple `git init` (and without the directory being a git repository before that), you should check your `~/.gitconfig` file, to see if it adds any pre-commit hooks by default.

Comment: NB: assuming `py` is indeed an alias of sorts for `python`, then I'd say this is a bad pre-commit hook in the first place, because it relies on some alias a user would have to define first.

Comment: @9769953 It's not an alias, it's a stupid Windows launcher that allows to have a few different Python versions in registry without putting any of them in `%PATH%`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50896577/7976758

Comment: @phd Sounds even worse. But `.git/hooks/pre-commit` seems very unix-y, not a Windows path. It's like this repository was cloned/copied, then attempting to be used for a new project with `git init`.

Comment: @9769953 I'm sure it's a `git-bash` terminal. Unix-like commands and directory paths in Windows. `/c/windows` must be added to `$PATH` for `py` to work in bash.

Comment: @phd Good point. I'd forgotten that exists. But overall, shouldn't there simply not be a pre-commit hook by default in the first place? And certainly not something that is so Windows specific.

Comment: @9769953 "*shouldn't there simply not be a pre-commit hook by default in the first place?*" Perhaps the OP did `git config --global core.hooksPath hooks` some time ago and forgot about the global hooks. Now they bit.

Comment: Oh... another thing I did. I installed git LFS

Comment: But did you check your git (global) configuration?

Comment: actually, I just ran `git config --global core.hooksPath hooks` by accident :D

Comment: and I updated git, which seems to have fixed the issue