# Installing requirements.txt in a venv inside VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv, requirements.txt

Apart from typing out commands - is there a good way to install `requirements.txt` inside `VSCode`.

I have a workspace with 2 folders containing different Python projects added - each has it's own virtual environment.  I would like to run a task to execute and install the requirements to each of these.

I have tried adding a task to `tasks.json` to try and do it for one with no success.

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Service1: Install requirements",
            "type": "shell",
            "runOptions": {},
            "command": "'${workspaceFolder}/sources/api/.venv/Scripts/activate'; pip install -r '${workspaceFolder}/sources/api/requirements.txt'",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

This runs - but you can see it refer to my global Python packages `h:\program files\python311\lib\site-packages` - not the virtual environment.

I am running on Windows for this - but would like it to work eventually with Linux.

Comment: It looks like an answer was added yesterday for a question asked in 2019 around setting up a venv in vscode.  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-can-i-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-in-visual-studio-code>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a more detailed [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75189721/13642249) before, but as Andez mentioned in comments, this is also a suitable post for the answer. This task can be ran in Windows, Linux and MacOS.

```
{

    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Python Env",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "linux": {
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
                },
                "command": "python3 -m venv py_venv && source py_venv/bin/activate && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt && deactivate py_venv"
            },
            "osx": {
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
                },
                "command": "python3 -m venv py_venv && source py_venv/bin/activate && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt && deactivate py_venv"
            },
            "windows": {
                "options": {
                    "shell": {
                        "executable": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
                        "args": [
                            "/d",
                            "/c"
                        ]
                    },
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
                },
                "command": "(if not exist py_venv py -m venv py_venv) && .\\py_venv\\Scripts\\activate.bat && py -m pip install --upgrade pip && py -m pip install -r requirements.txt && deactivate py_venv"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Windows example seems to assume that `py` is an alias for `python`. Also, I never tried custom tasks before, and didn't know how to start them. They're apparently available from the command palette, in "Tasks: Run Task". After the above file has been saved to `.vscode/tasks.json`

Comment: @EricDuminil Cool. Not sure how your `python` is [installed on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50896577/13642249), but I used `py` in this task with `cmd.exe` with the assumption that `py` points to the desired python3 version. In the more detailed [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75189721/13642249), I mentioned setting up the `task.json` file.

Comment: Interesting that this creates a new environment. VSC, or plugin, already creates a default one in `.venv/`. So after this task creates the one in `py_venv/` you get a popup "We noticed a new environment[...] Do you want to select it[...]?". Seems like a good idea to make certain you delete the old one, or risk accidentally using it in the future.