# conda geopandas installation and import

Tags: conda, geopandas

I'm completely new to jupypter and virtual env stuff...

Here is the case: I installed the geopandas in my conda env, and when I run py-3 and try to import it, it fails.

BUT

if I run python to launch, and import it, it works.

Anyone can help explain why???
[first try failed while second works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HJd1.png)

(I know how it works now, but just hope to figure out the backend principle behind all these stuff... little bit confusing to me now.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896496/what-is-the-difference-between-py-and-python-in-the-windows-terminal

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.