# How to use Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am in Windows 10 and I need to switch between Python environments. I found there is a program named "Anaconda" for that.

After installing the heavy (1GB) Anaconda installer, with default options the command prompt still does not recognize `conda` command.

I searched and then found there should be "Anaconda Prompt", so I did Windows search on that, however, no chance:

[image]

The only way I was able to launch something that recognizes this program is opening the Anaconda Navigator, that proposed me an update, and it's still loading that.

[image]

Is there a *simple* way to switch between Python environments?

Comment: There is a separate prompt for anaconda ...Seach `Anaconda Prompt` in the windows search

Comment: @Bhargav-RetardedSkills please read attentively the OP

Comment: Simple way is to not use Anaconda to be honest. There is a much smaller `miniconda`, there is `micromamba` (my preference). They are identical in features and packages to conda, but take very little space, and work much faster

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov the micromamba also gives me `error    libmamba No target prefix specified
critical libmamba Aborting.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add Anaconda (or miniconda, whatever) to your PATH. On Windows, search for "Path" on Start menu, and select "Edit environment variables for your account". Then, on the top square, select `Path`, and click `Edit...`. Then add the path to your conda's `Scripts` folder. You'll need to check your installation, mine is: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\miniconda3\Scripts` (changing `<USERNAME>` to my actual username.

This will bring `conda` into scope for new terminals. Then run `conda init`.

NOTE: [*miniconda*](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/miniconda/index.html) is just Anaconda without all its huge library of pre bundled packages. [The only difference](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/user-guide/install/index.html) (apart from the installed size) is that you need to install with `conda install` or `pip install` any packages you want. Generally speaking, Anaconda is unecessary for most users.

Comment: what for serves the installer if it doe snot add to the path? how should I search now for the anaconda/miniconda path? why there are two ana and mini installed? I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is not simple. If you are looking for a simple way to switch between Python versions or environments, maybe look at `pyenv`.

On Windows, there is also [the `py` wrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) which lets you select which of one or more installed Python versions to use.

Any nontrivial software installation requires you to understand how the `PATH` works, and do basic troubleshooting. We have hundreds of previous questions about that topic; see e.g. [Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows) for your immediate problem.

What Anaconda provides is a package manager which handles complex dependencies. It is fairly popular in the scientific community, where you frequently need to manage complex interdependencies between third-party libraries, application suites, and scripts. If that's what you actually need, godspeed; but for merely managing your Python installation, it is arguably overkill.

Comment: the problem is the installer is buggy or bug prone. Why the Anaconda prompt does not recognize conda? why I need 1GB installer? where should I search for the path to add to path env variable? where to search docs for py wrapper?

Comment: I am on Windows, and Pyenv does not officially support Windows

Comment: by the way, "hundreds of previous questions" means the program is not intuitive, buggy and hard to understand

Comment: "The program" here being Windows; I couldn't agree more. Unfortunately, Windows users tend to be baffled or even offended when we suggest they get rid if it.

Comment: if a software editor (of Anaconda) can't adapt its product to the OS that takes 80% of the market, I think there is a problem in the editor, not in the market or the OS.

Comment: I added a link to the `py` documentation. Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896496/what-is-the-difference-between-py-and-python-in-the-windows-terminal

Comment: Which "editor" are we suddenly talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I installed [micromamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/micromamba.html) as Alexey [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78242979/how-to-use-anaconda#comment137940598_78242979).

1. Installation in PowerShell:

   ```
   Invoke-Expression ((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://micro.mamba.pm/install.ps1).Content)
   ```
2. set `MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX` to `c:\micromamba`

   ```
   micromamba -r c:\micromamba
   ```

and was able finally to get

```
micromamba create -n myenv
micromamba activate myenv
```