# Can't find python in Environment variables path although it is added to path?

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-3.9

"python" command in cmd works just fine, which I believe means that python is added to path. I can't find it in PATH in Environment variables tho. The reason Im messing with this is because I want to remove python 3.10 from path to and to add python 3.9.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743281/cant-set-python-environment-path-variable

Comment: Doesn't really help. The problem is that I have python in path, but it is not shown, so I can't remove it and instead put there the folder for python 3.9 to be used.

Comment: use `where python` to know the path of python first. Then follow this to remove python https://stackoverflow.com/a/60318668/1836069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` environment variable only store the paths to the directory to find commands or executable files. If you're on Linux or Mac OS, you can find where the `python` path is from using the command

```
which python
```

which will then reveal the path to the python executable like below example

```
/usr/bin/python
```

You can then see where the path is linked to which version of Python using the command `ls -l <path to python executable>`

```
> ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

If you want to link `python` command to a specific version of python executable, you can add this line to either `.zshrc` (zsh shell) or `.bashrc` (bash shell) depending on which shell your terminal is using

```
alias python='</path/to/python3/executable>'
```

Comment: I'm using Windows. And I have found the Environment variable, it was just well hidden under some AppData folders. Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use multiple python versions with pyenv

https://youtu.be/HTx18uyyHw8